# ListView item deletion changes item heights

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have a `ListView` whose items can be deleted by swiping them. When an item is swiped, its database row gets deleted, as well as its object in the adapter's data set, and `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called as well. The problem is, these items have varying heights - one can be a one-liner, the second can have four lines. So when I have some items on the list, let's say:

1.One line

2.Two lines

3.Three lines

4.One line

And the second one is deleted, the third one goes in its place (as expected), but gets cut off to two lines. And when the third one is deleted, the fourth item's height is increased to match the deleted item's.

I found a way to fix that, however it's probably a wrong one - it creates a new view even if a convertView is not null.

I wonder if this can be achieved in another, recycling-friendly way.

Current adapter code:

```
public class CounterItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<CounterItem> data;
    private SQLiteOpenHelper helper;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CounterItemAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<CounterItem> data, SQLiteOpenHelper helper) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.data = data;
        this.helper = helper;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    @Override
    public CounterItem getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getItem(position).getId();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        //if(convertView == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter_list_item, null);
        TextView nameView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nameView);

        //other, unrelated views were here

        final CounterItem counterItem;
        counterItem = getItem(position);

        nameView.setText(counterItem.getName());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i've found a solution.

Added `int lastValidPosition = -1;`
in the adapter, then `adapter.lastValidPosition = position-1`
in the deletion callback method, before `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
, and in the `getView()` method of the adapter i've changed

```
//if(convertView == null)
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter_list_item, null);
```

to

```
if(lastValidPosition < position | convertView == null){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter_list_item, null);
    lastValidPosition = position;
}
```

and it works perfectly.